# Cookie rewrite not working properly on moovweb

Tags: cookies, moovweb

I just realized that cookie rewrite is not working in a moovweb project I am working.
I have written host map as

```
{
    "host_map": [
        "$.subdomain.domain.com => subdomain.domain.com"
    ]
}
```

When I checked cookie on mlocal server of moovweb, few session cookie still have domain "subdomain.domain.com" , which I was expecting to be ".subdomain.domain.com" .
And because of that those session cookie are not getting added on ajax request for url mlocal.subdomain.domain.com which is causing request fail.

I am new on moovweb, can anyone please tell me, if I need to do more configuration for it .

Comment: Is it possible those cookies are being set via JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

The notation "$.subdomain.domain.com" implies that locally you can add a local variable before the . to access your experience. The default value is mlocal, though you can change it.

Running local, all your requests should come.

You can do `moov server -help` to get more information.

JC